# How to detect what crypto-method is used by Filecoder.Q?

Tags: encryption, key-recovery, ransomware

I have 2 different images, one original, and one locked by a malware detected by eset as "**Win32/Filecoder.Q**".

How to detect the encryption method that is used and the key, that is not using any public key/rsa/rc4 algorithm. There is diff:

[image: original file]
[image: locked file]

If needed I can attached files (locked and original).

Comment: Why is there a short red line between `yvc` and `.O°` for the locked file? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer It's a delimited to show that file headers are not touched (i draw it)

Comment: Why do you say "not using" "RSA/RC4"? How do you know that? Also, even if it is using a symmetric algorithm, the key is probably not in the encrypted file, so looking at it does not help.

Comment: @otus because it's a scriptkiddy realisation. Having these files can't find key anyway?

Comment: @Daniel probably not. See related questions about [CryptoLocker](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11254/knowing-pre-encryption-data-can-we-find-the-private-key-cryptolocker-used) and [CryptoWall](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27692/knowing-pre-encryption-data-can-we-find-the-private-key-cryptowall-used).

Answer (score 1):

Filecoder.Q ransomware used one of three encryption algorithms: XOR ,Tiny Encryption Algorithm(TEA) and AES,but this ransomware does not encrypt beginning of the files so in your picture beginning of original and locked file are equal.if this ransomware uses XOR Algorithm then you can decrypt locked file with XORing original file and locked file(key Extraction) else if it uses TEA Algorithm then decryption of file is hard(but possible),but decryption of file when it uses AES is impossible.

Comment: Why do you say decryption is possible with TEA? It is [secure](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/is-tea-considered-secure), AFAIK. Do you mean some kind of attack exploiting its small block size?

Comment: I tried to find key, for XOR algorithm, but no success

Comment: @otus i speak about some cryptanalysis of TEA  like  this link:https://www.schneier.com/cryptography/archives/1997/11/related-key_cryptana.html

Comment: @Daniel you should XOR bits of original file with equivalent bits of  locked file and the result is key,or you can use ESET Filecoder.Q Cleaner

Comment: @0skar, those are related key attacks, which are pretty much not useful in practice.

Comment: @0skar Tried all of this. Maybe i was wrong saying it's written by a scriptkiddy. It's a more complex software i see.